# Class identifier without risk of integer overflow

Tags: java, oop

Is there any smart solution to avoid the risk of integer overflow when you try to give an unique identifier to each object of a class ?

For example, in Java :

if I have an attribute like this

```java
private static int nextID = 0;
```

and my constructor looks like

```java
    public MyClass() {
        this.id = nextID++;
    }
```

In all likelyhood, if I create too many objects, I will get an integer overflow and the ID will no longer be a unique value.

How could I avoid this behavior ?

Comment: You can use `long` instead of `int`, which will reduce the likelihood of overflow.

Comment: I should note that your current constructor is not thread-safe.  If you are going to use incrementing counter to generate ids, you *probably* should use an `AtomicXXX` type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Even if you use Longs, if you create more than 2^64 objects you will eventually exhaust your unique IDs.

If you want to use IDs that won't be exhausted for a long long time, use UUIDs.

Comment: Eventually means about 600 years in the worst case:)